# Is it a good idea to create a commit after switching to a tag pointing to an older commit?

Tags: git

If yes, when would this be useful? Will I lose any newer commits? If I do this, I'm getting some message to create a new branch because I'm leaving 1 commit behind. My head hurts...

Comment: Creating a new branch is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid loosing your commits made after you switched to a tag, you need to create a branch (doesn't matter whether it's created before or after you made the commits).

```
git branch -b changes-after-tag
```

Until a branch is created, you are in a detached HEAD state, which means that your commits aren't made on a branch. The consequence is that if you check out another branch or tag, recovering these commits will be difficult, if not lost at all after a repository cleanup. Creating a branch keep them safe.